# Double-bagging problem: which bag on the inside?

Tags: structural-engineering

If you're double-bagging some groceries, and one of the bags has tears in it while the other is intact, which bag should go on the inside?

Comment: This would largely depend on the degree of tearing & the location of the tear(s) & thus how useful the teared bag might be. It also depends on the material the bags are made of. This is very broad.

Comment: Take the objects out of the torn bag, put them in the new bag, then put the new bag inside the torn one... Or do what we all do and put the new bag over the torn one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the torn bag inside, just to let it absorb the possible moisture of veggies and other freshly washed fruits.

It is interesting to note that some tears at critical locations where they could concentrate stress to outer bag can lead to tearing of the outer bag, while left alone by itself it could safely contain it's load. Same idea as the shallow scorelines the glazing guys put on a plane of glass to cut it.